# R - escape single quote in string

Tags: r, escaping, system, bcp

I am using R to script a bcp/sql file export via the system() command.

My code looks like this:

```
system('bcp "SELECT top 1000 
    \'0 \' + \' \'
    + [id]
    + \' |hr \' + SUBSTRING(hour, 7,8) 
    + \' |dw \' + substring(datename(dw, substring([hour],1,6) ),1,2)
    + \' |C1 \' + [C1]
    FROM [mydb].[dbo].[table1];" queryout "C:\\Users\\me\\out1.csv" -T -c -t')
```

This creates a file that looks like this:

```
0  11109837967897642393 |hr 19 |dw Fr |C1 1005
0  11109872938080795857 |hr 19 |dw Fr |C1 1005
0  1110995254810489060 |hr 19 |dw Fr |C1 1005
```

What I need is a single quote in front of the id #:

```
0  '11109837967897642393 |hr 19 |dw Fr |C1 1005
0  '11109872938080795857 |hr 19 |dw Fr |C1 1005
0  '1110995254810489060 |hr 19 |dw Fr |C1 1005
```

I can't figure out how to properly deal with inserting that quote.  I've tried:

```
 system('bcp "SELECT top 1000 
        \'0 \' + \' '\'
        + [id]

 system('bcp "SELECT top 1000 
        \'0 \' + \' "'"\'
        + [id]
```

and several others.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I think we need to see the bcp code that produces the right output (when you run it directly, from the terminal). Then we can help you construct that string in R.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `\'0 \' + \' \' +\'\'\'` or `\'0 \' + \' \'+\"\'\"`